# calling the set function from a useState using the arrow function method reloads too early

Tags: reactjs

So im trying to set an array on the context when a http request fails in a custom hook

Here is my hook:

```
const useHttp = (requestObj: any, setData: Function) => 
{
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false); 
    const ctx = useContext(GlobalContext);
        
    const sendRequest = useCallback(() =>
    {
        setIsLoading(true);
        
        fetch(requestObj.url, {
            method: requestObj.method ? requestObj.method: 'GET',
            headers: requestObj.headers ? requestObj.headers : {},
            body: requestObj.body ? JSON.stringify(requestObj.body) : null
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            setIsLoading(false);
            setData(data);                
        })
        .catch(err => 
        {
            setIsLoading(false); 
            ctx.setErrors([
            (prevErrors: string[]) =>
            {
                //prevErrors.push(err.message)
                let newArray = prevErrors.map((error) => {return error});
                newArray.push(err.message);
                return newArray;
            }]
        );
            console.log('There was an error');
        });
    }, []);

    return {
        isLoading: isLoading,
        sendRequest: sendRequest
    }
}
```

Im setting the array using the previous state value. Im using .map cos the spread operator for arrays isnt working. Im looking into it but its not important for this.

When it hits setErrors it seems to be causing the revealuation of the component where that is used (below). I thought it wouldnt update until the function is fired. The problem then is that when it reevaluated errors is an array with the function from the hook in the first element. So im not sure what to do here

```
const App: FC = () => {

    const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);

    let modal = null

    if(errors.length > 0)
    {
        modal = ( 
            <Modal 
                heading="Warning" 
                content={<div>{errors}</div>}
                buttonList={
                    [
                        {label: "OK", clickHandler: ()=> {}, closesModal: true},
                        {label: "Cancel", clickHandler: ()=> {alert("cancelled")}, closesModal: false}
                    ]
                } 
                isOpen={true}/>
        )
    }

    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider value={{errors: errors, setErrors: setErrors}}>
            <ProviderV3 theme={defaultTheme}>
                <Toolbar></Toolbar>
                <Grid
                    margin='25px'
                    columns='50% 50%'
                    gap='10px'
                    maxWidth='100vw'>
                    <OwnerSearch />
                    <NewOwnerSearch />
                </Grid>
            </ProviderV3>
            {modal}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accidentally placed the array brackets around the function:

```
ctx.setErrors((prevErrors: string[]) => {
  //prevErrors.push(err.message)
  let newArray = prevErrors.map((error) => {return error});
  newArray.push(err.message);
  return newArray;
})
```